# nested directive throws Error: [$compile:multidir]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a very simple nested directive that just simply throws an error.  I can call the base-directive without error, but when I add my-directive which calls base-directive I get the error.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <base-directive>This is the base directive</base-directive> 
    <my-directive>this is my directive</my-directive> 
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDKNj0Ki4mRgudmTTUAP

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .directive('baseDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template   : '<div>base-directive:transclusion=<ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>'
        };
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,       
            transclude:true,
            template   : '<base-directive><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></base-directive>'
        }
    })
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      }])
```

Here's the error:

Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [myDirective, baseDirective] asking for transclusion on: 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/$compile/multidir?p0=myDirective&p1=baseDirective&p2=transclusion&p3=%3Cbase-directive%3E
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:68)
    at assertNoDuplicate (angular.js:8065)
    at applyDirectivesToNode (angular.js:7480)
    at compileNodes (angular.js:7117)
    at compileNodes (angular.js:7129)
    at compileNodes (angular.js:7129)
    at compile (angular.js:7024)
    at angular.js:1519
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15236)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15335)

**What I'm trying to do:**

I was hoping to create a few base directives that present a portion of the UI, and some higher level directives that call these base directives to build a complete "widget".

## Update 1 - without multiple transclusion

As suggested by @Claies, I cannot have multiple transclusions, but it must be more than that, because even with this version where I pass in the text, and only have transclusion in base, I get the error:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,       
        scope: {
          text: '@' 
        },
        template   : '<base-directive>{{text}}</base-directive>'
    }
})
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  }])

<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <base-directive>This is the base directive</base-directive> 
    <my-directive text="this is my directive"></my-directive> 
</div>

Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [myDirective, baseDirective] asking for template on: <base-directive text="this is my directive">
```

Comment: you might want to use non-minified angular first, to get a more meaningful error message (  `Multiple directives [myDirective, baseDirective] asking for transclusion on: <base-directive> in your case` )

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the more readable form.

Comment: you can't nest transclusions.  Since transclusion replaces the innerHTML, it will only be possible to apply it to the innermost element.

Comment: I took it out in update 1, so now it looks like I also cannot have templating in my higher level directive.  I'm not sure how I'm going to create a "widget" with directives... hmmm

Comment: well that's a different issue, first error was `transclusion`, after the change, the error is `template`.

Comment: can you try adding `require: '^baseDirective'` to the definition of `myDirective`?

Comment: As @entre points out the error indicates that one cannot have one directive with a template call another directive with a template which is essential to what I'm trying to do.  So I'm stuck.  I did try the require, but it didn't change the error message.